# How to round up to the nearest 100 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I want to round up to the *nearest* 100 all the time whether or not the value is 101 or 199 it should round up to 200.  For example:

```
var number = 1233;
//use something like Math.round() to round up to always 1300
```

I'd like to always round up to the nearest 100, never round down, using jQuery.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil()`, if you want to always round up:

```
Math.ceil(number/100)*100
```

Answer (score 31):

To round up *and* down to the nearest 100 use `Math.round`:

```
Math.round(number/100)*100
```

`round` vs. `ceil`:

> `Math.round(60/100)*100 = 100` vs. `Math.ceil(60/100)*100 = 100`
>
> `Math.round(40/100)*100 = 0` vs. `Math.ceil(40/100)*100 = 100`
>
> `Math.round(-60/100)*100 = -100` vs. `Math.ceil(-60/100)*100 = -0`
>
> `Math.round(-40/100)*100 = -0` vs. `Math.ceil(-40/100)*100 = -0`

Answer (score 9):

No part of this requires jQuery. Just use JavaScript's [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
Math.ceil(x / 100) * 100
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution would be:

```js
Math.round(number/100)*100
```

Answer (score 1):

This is  an easy way to do it:

```
((x/100).toFixed()*100;
```