# Ruby Round Up to Next Hundred

Tags: ruby, rounding

How can I round up to the next hundred?  Using Ruby 2.3.2.

`48 -> 100
52 -> 100
112 -> 200`

Tried `48.round(-2)` but that rounds down.  Trialed some BigDecimal values, but that got me nowhere.

Comment: Searching Google for "round number to next hundred" returns a number of hits, including some on SO, which help explain it such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/19621455/128421, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8866046/128421

Comment: Another way: `def roundup(n) 100*(1+((n-1)/100)) end; roundup(248) #=> 300; roundup(400) #=> 400; roundup(-240) #=> -200; roundup(-200) #=> -200`.

Comment: Tin Man, several items on Google, whilst INCLUDING "Ruby", ran me into nothing but dead ends.  It's why I included the version number here.  Also, Ruby is not Javascript and has different methods and approaches.  Same with Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Divide by 100 first then multiply back.

```
(48/100.0).ceil * 100
```

Comment: I was close.  The significant figure is what would respect the remainder.  Thank you.

Comment: sometimes I wonder how can u people come up with such elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer#ceil`/`Float#ceil`, saying that you want it to round to two places before the comma:

```rb
48.ceil(-2)
```

This isn't available in Ruby 2.3.0, but it is in Ruby >= 2.4.0.

Comment: @Sujay, do you like this better? The accepted answer is right for Ruby 2.3.0, but nowadays there is a better way to round up to the next hundred.