# Simple Math Function Help in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

---

---

I am not much of a coder so i need some help in **Javascript** on a webpage i have been working on

> This is the webpage --> http://dawasco.unaux.com

I wanted to make a simple math function whereby:

1. When users enter an input value(lets call it x)  in the input box (box with solid blue border)
2. The value x is taken and then added with 0.01 or 1% of x

   > Basically : x + (0.01x)
3. Then 1000 is added to the result value i.e.

   > In this Case : 1.01x +1000
4. Finally the result is rounded **UP** to the nearest hundreds

   > So in this case if we take x=1 then the total ;1001.01 will be rounded up to 1100

---

### Example

1.
Lets say the input value is: **94,000**

2. 1% of 94,000 is 940 so:

   > 94,000 + 940 = **94940**
3. then 94940 is added with 1000 so:

   > 94940 + 1000 = **95940**

4.
the total i.e. 95940 is rounded Up to the nearest hundreds

> 95,940 = **96,000**

---

My questions are:
1. How do i set a parameter to round off the values in 100s. `math.ceil()` here
2. How do i connect the input box and the javascript file
3. How do i display the output in the output box?
4. I tried using variables but failed so basically i need a solution

Comment: If you have been working on this, share your [mcve] and explain the problem you are facing in your implementation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Note that the problem, as posted, has a (maybe unexpected) difficulty and could require arbitrary precision floats or similar.

Comment: Well i tried using the  `math.ceil() ` for rounding up the number i didnt know how to set a parameter which only rounded in 100s

Comment: _“i didnt know how to”_ - newsflash: This is the point were you are supposed to do some basic _research_! Typing something trivial such as “javascript round number to next 100” into Google would have led you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19621455/1427878 in no time.

Comment: @CBroe Hey Man!. I apologize if I annoyed or made you angry. I am still a learner and have a long way to go. I appreciate your help and thank you ! Have a Nice Day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should do the trick if you always want to round to the nearest hundred.

```
function computation(number) { 
  let newNumber = number + (1/100 * number) + 1000;
  let roundedNumber = Math.round(newNumber/100)*100;
  return roundedNumber;
}
```

Comment: This is great!  But how do I link the `<input>` and the `<output>` Tag?

Comment: Aha you should read the javascript documentation, I can't give you the exact answer, it depend on your HTML and Javascript code :)