# How to round an integer to the nearest hundred in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have a number

```js
let x = 890
```

and I want it to be rounded to 900

and if the number is 820 then it should be rounded to 800.

Let's also assume the input number (x) will always be an integer,

I know that we can solve this by manually checking if it is greater than 50 or not, but is there a simpler solution? preferably by recursion in javascript.

Comment: Math.round(x / 100) * 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just of the top of my head:

Take any number, divide it by hundred, round the number with `Math.round()`,  multiply by 100 to get your desired number.

```
const roundNumber = (num) => Math.round(num/100) *100
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round up and down.

`Math.round(number/100)*100`

For more indepth and also a comparison with `Math.ceil()` check out this link:

[How to round up to the nearest 100 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621455/how-to-round-up-to-the-nearest-100-in-javascript)